# HSQL why I get error when use GET DIAGNOTICS <variable> = ROW_COUNT

Tags: hsqldb

I want to get the value of rowcount (like other dbms provides the `@@rowcount`) from hsqldb in the store procedure, but I get confused about the exception that informs me that

> Unexpected Token: GET, required:END

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This syntax works in the latest HSQLDB 2.2.9 snapshot:

```
create procedure del_stuff(inout n int) modifies sql data
 begin atomic
 delete from t_temp where t_temp.i > n;
 get diagnostics n = row_count;
 end
```

Comment: Hi fredt, I know the exactly grammar, but the problem is still exist! and my current version is 2.2.4, is the problem of this version. I will try 2.2.9 version later.

Comment: In fact I want to write a program to convert the sybase stored procedure into the hsql stored procedure, do you think it is realistic? I compare the two stored procedure, there seems a lot of differences. So do you have any other suggestion on this problem, thank you very much!

Comment: This capability is new and not supported in version 2.2.4. I don't have any other suggestion.